# MRJob :- Display intermediate values in map reduce

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

How can I display intermediate values (i.e print a variable or a list ) on the terminal while running the mapreduce program using python MRJob library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can output the results to standard error using sys.stderr.write(). Here is an example:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import sys
class MRWordCounter(MRJob):
    def mapper(self, key, line):
        sys.stderr.write("MAPPER INPUT: ({0},{1})\n".format(key,line))
        for word in line.split():
            yield word, 1

    def reducer(self, word, occurrences):
        occurencesList= list(occurrences)
        sys.stderr.write("REDUCER INPUT: ({0},{1})\n".format(word,occurencesList))
        yield word, sum(occurencesList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordCounter.run()
```

Comment: For any future reference: You can also look in the temporary files the job creates. Both the mappers and the combined sorted output is stored in temporary files. MRjob outputs the path of the temporary files.